# postgreSQL Fibonacci Sequence - Query has no destination for result data

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, plpgsql, common-table-expression

So I wrote a Fibonacci sequence function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fibonacci (lastN INTEGER) 
RETURNS int AS $$
BEGIN
WITH RECURSIVE t(a, b) AS (
    VALUES(0,1)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT GREATEST(a, b), a + b AS a from t
        WHERE b < $1
)
SELECT a FROM t;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when I called:

```
SELECT * FROM fibonacci(20);
```

the console shows:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fibonacci(integer) line 5 at SQL statement
```

I think the Return statement should return the query result but it isn't. I'm completely a new guy on writing SQL functions like this.

Comment: try this: select fibonacci(20);

Comment: @anonyXmous still giving me the same error

Comment: @anonyXmous the problem was rather that the query was leading to nowhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Basically your `SELECT` is leading to nowhere and your function header says it is supposed to return a `INT` value. Since it is a pure `SQL` query using `CTE`, there is no need to use `PLPGSQL`, so I also changed the language type to `SQL`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fibonacci (lastN INTEGER) 
RETURNS SETOF INTEGER LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
WITH RECURSIVE t(a, b) AS (
    VALUES(0,1)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT GREATEST(a, b), a + b AS a from t
        WHERE b < $1
)
SELECT a FROM t;
$$;

SELECT fibonacci(20);
```

**EDIT:** as requested, the same function using the language `PLPGSQL`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fibonacci (lastN INTEGER) 
RETURNS SETOF INT LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY WITH RECURSIVE t(a, b) AS (
    VALUES(0,1)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT GREATEST(a, b), a + b AS a from t
        WHERE b < $1
)
SELECT a FROM t;
END $$;

SELECT fibonacci(20);
```

Comment: A quick explanation of the improvements you made would be helpful :)

Comment: just added a short explanation :-) Thanks for the kind remind

Comment: @JimJones Thanks for the explanation. But what if I want to use plpgsql to achieve this? How would you modify this query?

Comment: @TravisSu just added to my answer a `plpgsql` version of this function

Answer (score 0):

If one needs the complete Fibonacci numbers up to 92, may try this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tb(n, m1) AS (
    SELECT 
    1::bigint,
    0::bigint
  UNION ALL
    SELECT (n+m1)::bigint,n::bigint FROM tb
)
SELECT n FROM tb LIMIT 92;  -- Must have a limit, otherwise it will be looping forever
```