# Postgres approach to solving Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I'm trying to solve a question to generate the fibonacci sequence using SQL. Through my method, the query is timing out after about the 21st iteration call using the function through a series of `union all` against it.

```
create function f(bigint) returns bigint
  as 'select case
        when $1 = 0 then 0
        when $1 = 1 then 1
        when $1 = 2 then 1
        when $1 = 3 then 2
      else f($1-1) + f($1-2)
      end;'
language sql
immutable
returns null on null input;
```

current query to generate f(n) as rows in a table:

```
select f(0) as x
union all
select f(1) as x
union all
select f(2) as x
union all
...
select f(21) as x
```

Could `generate_series(start, end)` with `f(start),f(end)` somehow be leveraged? Did try this approach but it is not working it seems as it simply returns results from start to end and not the fibonacci sequence itself.

Any suggestions or alternate approached are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try one of the "examples" found when Googling for "postgresql fibonacci". the first [hit](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fibonacci_Numbers), and the second [hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307655/postgresql-fibonacci-sequence-query-has-no-destination-for-result-data) will probably not time out....

Comment: I did try one similar to the first link, but was going for my own angle first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Mike, my first thought was a recursive CTE.  However, I would phrase it as:

```
with recursive seed (n, fib_n, fib_n_minus_1) as (
       values (1::numeric, 1::numeric, 0::numeric)
      ),
      fib (n, fib_n, fib_n_minus_1) as (
       select n, fib_n, fib_n_minus_1
       from seed
       union all
       select n + 1, fib_n + fib_n_minus_1, fib_n
       from fib f
       where n < 1000
     )
select *
from fib
order by n;
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful. I just needed to cast the values to ```bigint``` to correctly display.

Answer (score 0):

A non-recursive solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."Fibbo"(
    hasta integer)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
declare 
    ante1 integer :=0;
    ante2 integer :=1;
    i integer := 0;
begin
    -- Valor cero
    raise notice 'Salida: % => %', i, ante1;
    
    -- De 1 a n
    loop exit when i>=hasta;    
        select ante2+ante1, ante1, i+1 into ante1, ante2, i;
        raise notice 'Salida: % => %', i, ante1;
    end loop;
    
    return ante1;
end;
```